# Netbeans Profiler output shows "The syntax of this command is incorrect."

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, syntax, profiler

I am trying to profile my Java with Maven project named "profilerTest" using Netbeans profiler, but when I attempt to profile my project the progress window gets stuck at "Connect to the target VM..." and the output shows the below command, followed by "The syntax of this command is incorrect."

```
cd C:\Users\MY\Documents\NetBeansProjects\profilerTest; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-16" cmd /c "\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-12.3\\netbeans\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.cmd\" -Dexec.args=\"-agentpath:\\\"C:/Program Files/NetBeans-12.3/netbeans/profiler/lib/deployed/jdk16/windows-amd64/profilerinterface.dll\\\"=\\\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-12.3\\netbeans\\profiler\\lib\\\",5140,10 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\\Users\\MY\\AppData\\Local\\NetBeans\\Cache\\12.3\\mavencachedirs\\1785015665\\org-netbeans-modules-profiler  -classpath %classpath GarbageCollector.GCollector\" -Dexec.executable=\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-16\\bin\\java.exe\" -Dprofiler.jvmargs.all=\" -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\\Users\\MY\\AppData\\Local\\NetBeans\\Cache\\12.3\\mavencachedirs\\1785015665\\org-netbeans-modules-profiler  -agentpath:\\\"C:/Program Files/NetBeans-12.3/netbeans/profiler/lib/deployed/jdk16/windows-amd64/profilerinterface.dll\\\"=\\\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-12.3\\netbeans\\profiler\\lib\\\",5140,10\" -Dprofiler.jvmargs.arg1=\"-agentpath:\\\"C:/Program Files/NetBeans-12.3/netbeans/profiler/lib/deployed/jdk16/windows-amd64/profilerinterface.dll\\\"=\\\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-12.3\\netbeans\\profiler\\lib\\\",5140,10\" -Dprofiler.jvmargs.arg2=-XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\\Users\\MY\\AppData\\Local\\NetBeans\\Cache\\12.3\\mavencachedirs\\1785015665\\org-netbeans-modules-profiler -Dprofiler.jvmargs.arg3=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-12.3\\netbeans\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 process-classes org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec"
```

**The following is my version of Netbeans:**

- Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 12.3
- Java: 16; Java HotSpot(TM)
  64-Bit Server VM 16+36-2231
- Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 16+36-2231
- System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_MY (nb)
- User directory: C:\Users\MY\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\12.3
- Cache directory: C:\Users\MY\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.3

I am using jdk 16, and the maven that is bundled with Netbeans. I've also tried looking at each file path in the command to see if any of the files were named wrongly/in the wrong path, but so far it appears fine to me. I have no idea what's wrong with the syntax of the command... would appreciate it if anyone could help me figure out the issue and how to solve it.

Comment: Consider upgrading to Netbeans 14 and Java 17 LTS.

Comment: NetBeans 12.3 does not support the use of Java 16. From [the Release Notes](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb123/nb123.html): _"Apache **NetBeans 12.3 runs on JDK LTS releases 8 and 11, as well as on JDK 15**, i.e., the current JDK release at the time of this NetBeans release."_ So you can either downgrade to JDK 15, or (as @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen suggests) upgrade to NetBeans 14/Java 17. Whether using JDK 16 is directly causing your problem is irrelevant because your environment is invalid. Fix your environment and update your question if the problem persists.